# Why is hostname resolution different with root/sudo?

Tags: networking, dns, hosts

If I give my NAT IP a hostname modifying `/etc/hosts` like ...

```
# ...
192.168.20.20 myname-local.de
```

and then `ping myname-local.de`, it is successful. But if I use `sudo` like `sudo ping myname-local.de`, it says

> unknown host

Why is that? And how do I make `root` care for my hostnames in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Try to "clear the cache" `sudo service networking restart` or  `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: Didn't help (as well as complete reboot which should imply restarting any service)...

Comment: In my system each modification I do on `/etc/hosts` is reflected immediately for my user and for sudo invocation...

Comment: I've been used to that, too... Seems to be a bug. Any further ideas?

Comment: Try to add an external site such as `64.233.165.106 googleee` and after use to do `ping googleee` and `sudo ping googleee`. Just a try.

Comment: Same result (`sudo ping googleee` prints `unknown host` and `ping googleee` succeeds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs if `/etc/hosts` is a symlink with target permissions and ownership `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root`. In order to include the file from another location, I use mount/bind now.

I'm not sure whether this is a bug...